# Changing format of JSON data to resemble JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to take the timestamp/close of the JSON data from `http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/goog/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/?callback=?`

To look like a JS array as in `http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=goog-c.json&callback=?`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gMs6n/ (**updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/gMs6n/2/) (view console to see data log)
Working version using Highcharts example: http://jsfiddle.net/gMs6n/1/

```
$(function () {

  // ajax in data 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true, jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: 'graph',
    url: 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/goog/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/?callback=graph', // http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=graph
    processData: false
  }).success(function(data) {

    // manipulate the data
    console.log(data);
    //JSON.parse(data);

    // create a new data object
    $.each(data.series, function (i, val) {
      for (var key in data.series[i]) {
        //console.log(key);
        console.log(data.series[i][key]); // how to pair up the timestamp/close in a new data object?
      }
    });

    // Create the chart
    /*
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      series: [{
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
    */


  });

});
```

I have tried `JSON.parse(data);` and `$.parseJSON(data);` but I am getting an error. I must be doing something wrong.

How do I manipulate it post-ajax so to end up with "data" that Highcharts could use? I am using `$.each` to iterate over the data to form the new data set. **How to pair up the timestamp/close in a new data object?**

Comment: Iterate over the data, creating new data from the old data that matches your desired output. `JSON.parse` and `$.parseJSON` are useless for this task, other than initially converting the json string into a javascript array/object, which jquery is already doing for you.

Comment: The data *already is* the JavaScript objects (not JSON, JSON is *text*). jQuery handles the conversion transparently if the dataType is "json" or "jsonp". Use a debugger in the success callback and inspect `data` and see what structure it contains - and use it appropriately.

Comment: sounds like a job for [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @kevinB that was my original though, but I was wondering if there was a better (more efficient) way of doing it. @ user2864740, thanks for the input. @ tenub, how would I use .map for this case?

Comment: @Steve No there isn't, you'll have to iterate over it one way or another. .map is one way of doing it, .each is another. Both are thouroughly documented here: http://api.jquery.com the usage of each will depend on what format the source data is in and in what format you want to convert it to.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm using `$.each`, once I get something working, I'll update the question w/ the solution. Thanks again for your input. :)

Comment: If you come up with a solution, post it as an answer to your own question instead so that you can mark it as accepted

Comment: @kevinB, will do. See my edit above. I am wondering how to pair up the timestamp/close in a new data object?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for or at least take you closer to the goal:

```
  }).success(function(data) {
   var series = data.series.map(function(data){ return [data.Timestamp, data.close] ;   });
// manipulate the data
  console.log(series[0]);
```

This will result in one single array with this format:

```
[1389018600, 1114.25]
```

This the updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gMs6n/4/

Answer (score 0):

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/gMs6n/5/

```
$(function () {

  // ajax in data 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true, jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: 'graph',
    url: 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/goog/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/?callback=graph', // http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=graph
    processData: false
  }).success(function(data) {

    // manipulate the data
    //console.log(data);
    //JSON.parse(data);
    var chartData = [];

    $.each(data.series, function (i, val) {
      for (var key in data.series[i]) {
        //console.log(key);
        //console.log(data.series[i][key]); 
      }
      var chartTime = data.series[i].Timestamp;
      var chartClose = data.series[i].close;
      //console.log(data.series[i]);
      //console.log(chartTime);
      chartData.push([chartTime, chartClose]);
    });

    console.log(chartData);


    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      series: [{
        data: chartData,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });

  });

});
```